# Creating a self-updating Textblock user control in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm trying to create a re-usable textblock user control in WPF. The basic idea is as follows:

- User does not directly specify the content of the textblock
- There are three dependancy properties in my user control called `IsToggled`, `ToggleTrueText`, and `ToggleFalseText`.
- The control will display `ToggleTrueText` if `IsToggled` is true; or display `ToggleFalseText` if `IsToggled` is false.
- When `IsToggled` changes during runtime, the text automatically changes to either `ToggleTrueText` or `ToggleFalseText`

I started by adding a `PropertyChangedCallback` to the `IsToggled` DP:

Code-behind of the UserControl:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsToggledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsToggled", typeof(bool), 
        typeof(TagToggle), new PropertyMetadata(new 
        PropertyChangedCallback(OnToggleStateChanged)));

public bool IsToggled
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsToggledProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsToggledProperty, value); }
}

//ToggleTrueText and ToggleFalseText are declared similarly to IsToggled
```

...

```
private static void OnToggleStateChanged(DependencyObject d, 
 DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Xaml of the user control:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock x:Name="TheTextBlock" Text="{Binding WhatDoIBindTo}"/>
</Grid>
```

However, I'm not sure what would be the best way to ensure that `TheTextBlock` updates its text whenever IsToggled changes during runtime.

Comment: It's impossible to know, since you didn't bother to provide a [mcve] showing us what you're doing. But assuming the `Grid` and its `TextBlock` are in the `UserControl` XAML, then you should have a view model private to the `UserControl` that can be used as the data context for the `TextBlock`. Either that or just set the property explicitly as `TheTextBlock.Text` in the `OnToggleStateChanged()` method. Please improve the question so it's clear what you're doing and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: why dont you just create a CLR property and bind it to your textblock text property and dont forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static void OnToggleStateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TagToggle ctrl = d as TagToggle;
    if (ctrl != null)
    {
        TheTextBlock.Text = ctrl.IsToggled ? ToggleTrueText. : ToggleFalseText;
    }
}
```

If you want to bind the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` you need to make sure that you are binding to properties of the `UserControl`. You could do this by setting the `DataContext` property of the `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TheTextBlock" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ToggleTrueText}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsToggled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ToggleFalseText}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used trigger for this 
Please check below code

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TheTextBlock">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsToggled}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ToggleTrueText}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsToggled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ToggleFalseText}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```